# Soap wrong type: java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, soap

I generated a web service client using wsimport. After that I try to make a call to the web service like that:

```
    public void getUnidade(String username) {
        try {

            UnidadeEndPointService unidadeEndPointService = new UnidadeEndPointService();
            UnidadeEndPoint unidadeEndPointPort = unidadeEndPointService.getUnidadeEndPointPort();

            ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
            ParametroUnidadeDTO parametroUnidadeDTO = objectFactory.createParametroUnidadeDTO();
            //set data for parametroUnidadeDTO

            UnidadeResponse unidadeResponse = (UnidadeResponse) unidadeEndPointPort.getTemporaryUnit(parametroUnidadeDTO); //this line generates error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.somepackage.RetornoResponse incompatible with com.somepackage.UnidadeResponse

        } catch (WebServiceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I can not understand the reason I'm getting this java.lang.ClassCastException, since in the response it seems I'm receiving a UnidadeResponse, not a RetornoResponse:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <rpcOp:getTemporaryUnitResponse
            xmlns:rpcOp="http://someaddress.com/"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <return
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="UnidadeResponse">
                <codRet>0</codRet>
                <cdTemporaryUnit>00</cdTemporaryUnit>
                <cdTemporaryUpperUnit>00</cdTemporaryUpperUnit>
            </return>
        </rpcOp:getTemporaryUnitResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Observation: UnidadeResponse extends RetornoResponse

I need a UnidadeResponse because it contains the field cdTemporaryUpperUnit and RetornoResponse does not contain it. Do you have any idea why I'm getting the wrong object type?

RetornoResponse.java

```
//
// Generated By:JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01 (JAXB RI IBM 2.2.4-2)
//


package somepackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for retornoResponse complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="retornoResponse">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="codRet" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *         &lt;element name="msgRet" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" minOccurs="0"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "retornoResponse", propOrder = {
    "codRet",
    "msgRet"
})
public class RetornoResponse {

    protected String codRet;
    protected String msgRet;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the codRet property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCodRet() {
        return codRet;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the codRet property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCodRet(String value) {
        this.codRet = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the msgRet property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getMsgRet() {
        return msgRet;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the msgRet property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setMsgRet(String value) {
        this.msgRet = value;
    }

}
```

UnidadeResponse.java

```
//
// Generated By:JAX-WS RI 2.2.4-b01 (JAXB RI IBM 2.2.4-2)
//


package somepackage;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for UnidadeResponse complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType name="UnidadeResponse">
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;extension base="{http://someaddress/}retornoResponse">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="cdTemporaryUnit" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *         &lt;element name="cdTemporaryUpperUnit" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/extension>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "UnidadeResponse", propOrder = {
    "cdTemporaryUnit",
    "cdTemporaryUpperUnit"
})
public class UnidadeResponse
    extends RetornoResponse
{

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String cdTemporaryUnit;
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String cdTemporaryUpperUnit;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the cdTemporaryUnit property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCdTemporaryUnit() {
        return cdTemporaryUnit;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the cdTemporaryUnit property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCdTemporaryUnit(String value) {
        this.cdTemporaryUnit = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the value of the cdTemporaryUpperUnit property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public String getCdTemporaryUpperUnit() {
        return cdTemporaryUpperUnit;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the cdTemporaryUpperUnit property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link String }
     *     
     */
    public void setCdTemporaryUpperUnit(String value) {
        this.cdTemporaryUpperUnit = value;
    }

}
```

WSDL

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:tns="http://someaddress/" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" name="UnidadeEndPointService" targetNamespace="http://someaddress/">
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://someaddress/" schemaLocation="UnidadeEndPointService_schema1.xsd"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="getTemporaryUnit">
<part name="ParametroUsuarioDTO" type="tns:parametroUnidadeDTO"> </part>
</message>
<message name="WebServiceException">
<part name="fault" element="tns:WebServiceException"> </part>
</message>
<message name="getTemporaryUnitResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:retornoResponse"> </part>
</message>
<portType name="UnidadeEndPoint">
<operation name="getTemporaryUnit">
<input message="tns:getTemporaryUnit" wsam:Action="http://someaddress/UnidadeEndPoint/getTemporaryUnitRequest"> </input>
<output message="tns:getTemporaryUnitResponse" wsam:Action="http://someaddress/UnidadeEndPoint/getTemporaryUnitResponse"> </output>
<fault name="WebServiceException" message="tns:WebServiceException" wsam:Action="http://someaddress/UnidadeEndPoint/getTemporaryUnit/Fault/WebServiceException"> </fault>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="UnidadeEndPointPortBinding" type="tns:UnidadeEndPoint">
<soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="getTemporaryUnit">
<soap:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://someaddress/"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="http://someaddress/"/>
</output>
<fault name="WebServiceException">
<soap:fault name="WebServiceException" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="UnidadeEndPointService">
<port name="UnidadeEndPointPort" binding="tns:UnidadeEndPointPortBinding">
<soap:address location="http://someanotherddress/UnidadeEndPointService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://someaddress/" version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://someaddress/">
<xs:element name="WebServiceException" nillable="true" type="tns:faultInfo"/>
<xs:complexType name="parametroUnidadeDTO">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:cpaBaseDto">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="codigoLocalMatricula" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="tipo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="cpaBaseDto">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="operacao" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UsuarioDTO">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:cpaBaseDto">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="codigoLocalMatricula" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="tipo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UnidadeDTO">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:cpaBaseDto">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="codigoLocalMatricula" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="tipo" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="retornoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="codRet" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="msgRet" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UsuarioResponse">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:retornoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="cdTemporaryPosition" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="UnidadeResponse">
<xs:complexContent>
<xs:extension base="tns:retornoResponse">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="cdTemporaryUnit" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="cdTemporaryUpperUnit" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="faultInfo">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="code" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Thank you.

UPDATE/SOLUTION:

I created all code above based on wsimport generated classes. I tried using Axis to generate code, but same problem. So I talked to the owner of the Web Service who did some adjustments and now It's working. I noted that for example in WSDL changed the return type:

```
<message name="getTemporaryUnitResponse">
<part name="return" type="tns:UnidadeResponse"> </part>
</message>
```

Basically it was an error in the Web Service side.

Comment: Show your WSDL and XSD.

Comment: mentallurg, I posted my WSDL and XSD. Can you take a look please. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in WSDL and XSD. The XSD type *UnidadeResponse* extends *retornoResponse* and the generated class *UnidadeResponse* should extend *RetornoResponse*. I suppose that the generated class *UnidadeResponse* does not extend *RetornoResponse*. 1) Please show the source code of the classes *UnidadeResponse* and *RetornoResponse*. 2) Do you use binding file? If yes, please show its contents.

Comment: mentallurg, I just added the classes source code. The problem is the call unidadeEndPointPort.getTemporaryUnit(parametroUnidadeDTO) returns an RetornoResponse and not the subclass UnidadeResponse. Can you think of a reason why it happens?

Comment: The code was generated correctly, UnidadeResponse is really a subclass of RetornoResponse. This corresponds to XSD. This part is good. The error message means, that the response Object is really if type RetornoResponse. Now we should check the message. The SOAP response looks OK. But how did you get it? Have you dumped the traffic? Or you only *suppose* what should be the response?

Comment: 1) Replace `UnidadeResponse unidadeResponse = (UnidadeResponse) unidadeEndPointPort.getTemporaryUnit(parametroUnidadeDTO)` with `RetornoResponse retornoResponse =  unidadeEndPointPort.getTemporaryUnit(parametroUnidadeDTO);    System.out.println(retornoResponse);`. Then we will see what is the real type of the response.

Comment: 2) Check what is the real content of SOAP response. Does it really corresponds a hint to the type Unidade... or may be it it really RetornoResponse. If the latter is true,. this would mean that the service really send response if other type, RetornoResponse.

Comment: 1) this works but I'm not able to access the specific fields for UnidadeResponse, only fields from RetornoResponse. 2)The real SOAP response I got from log and is already in the question above, I not supposed it should be it, It's directly from the log.